# Ref string parameter is empty?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I want to call in C# a function from unmanaged library with following signature:

```cpp
DLL_EXPORT  int xli_open(char *, int , struct t_info *);
```

In legacy code on Windows 7 the function is improrted as:

```cs
[DllImport(DRIVER_FILENAME, EntryPoint = "xli_open", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int xli_open(string device, int hndl, ref t_info tInfo);
```

On Windows 10 I get an AccessViolationException for calling the function and I import the function as:

```cs
[DllImport(DRIVER_FILENAME, EntryPoint = "xli_open", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int xli_open(ref string device, int hndl, ref t_info tInfo);
```

I don't get AccessViolationException anymore, but it seems that the function gets an empty string. Is the declaration right? And why does the pass of the `ref` parameter work (would string not be passed by reference anyway?)?

Comment: What does your DLL_EXPORT expand into, and how does the code that calls `xli_open` look?

Comment: @GSerg That is library created with c and I don't have a code for the function, the declaration comes from header. I call the function as:               `var device = "c_xli_ctrl_1";
                t_info tInfo = new t_info();
                ctrl_ed = NativeFunctions.xli_open(ref device, XliConsts.TO_RDWR, ref tInfo);`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are passing the text to the function, then  plain by value `string` is correct. The access violation is likely because of some other error. Perhaps the structure definition does not match, perhaps the calling convention is wrong. Or perhaps some other mistake, but the `string` argument appears to be correct.